# How to find the number of unique occurrences for an Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array, containing `n` amount of elements. Each element contains two words.

This makes the array look like this: `['England John', 'England Ben', 'USA Paul', 'England John']`

I want to find the number of unique names for each country. For example, `England` would have 2 unique names as `John` exists two times.

So far I have split the array into two arrays, one containing the countries such as `['England', 'Usa', ...]` and the other containing names `['John', 'Paul', ...]`, however I'm unsure of where to go from here

Comment: Sounds like you want to use some kind of multi-map structure rather than an array, where the Country is the key and the names the values

Answer (score 5):

One liner option:

```
ary.uniq.group_by { |e| e.split.first }.transform_values(&:count)
#=> {"England"=>2, "USA"=>1}
```

Comment: Note that `transform_values` is an ActiveSupport method. If you're not using rails, you can replace it with `map { |country, occurrences| [country, occurences.count] }.to_h`.

Comment: @ndnenkov, `transform_values` is pure Ruby: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values, but for older Ruby your option is ok.

Comment: ndnenkov and @pascalbetz, [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) (and `transform_values!`, `transform_keys` and `transform_keys!`) made it's debut in Ruby v2.4.

Comment: @iGian Thank you for your reply. Please could you explain what the different parts do? I'm especially confused by the ```{ |e| e.split.first }``` bit, and the ```transform_values(&:count)``` bit

Comment: @BenWilliams I'd suggest you run the code step by step: `ary.uniq`, then `ary.uniq.group_by { |e| e.split.first }` and so on. `|e|` is the variable that contains the string which is splitted into an array of which we take the first element: `"a b".split.first` returns `"a"`, which is the value used for grouping. For `transform_values`, please see the comments above.

Answer (score 3):

The problem, really, is that you're storing this data as an array of strings. This is a poor choice of data structure, as it makes manipulation much harder.

Suppose, for example, we first convert this data into a `Hash`, which maps each country to the list of names:

```
data = ['England John', 'England Ben', 'USA Paul', 'England John']

mapped_names = {}

data.each do |item|
  country, name = item.split
  mapped_names[country] ||= []
  mapped_names[country] << name
end
```

Now, obtaining the count is quite easy:

```
mapped_name_counts = unique_names.transform_values { |names| names.uniq.count }
```

The resulting variables are:

```
mapped_names # => {"England"=>["John", "Ben", "John"], "USA"=>["Paul"]}
mapped_name_counts # => {"England"=>2, "USA"=>1}
```

And if using ruby version 2.7 (not yet released!!), that last line of code could even be simplified to:

```
mapped_name_counts = unique_names.tally(&:uniq)
```

Comment: It looks like you switched from the name `unique_names` to `mapped_names`, but didn't change all occurrences of the former. No reply needed. I'll delete this comment when you've seen it.

Comment: It looks like [Enumerable#tally](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/03/03/ruby-2-7-enumerable-tally.html) will be quite useful.

Comment: @CarySwoveland [Yep, I agree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48053739/1954610)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ['England John', 'England Ben', 'USA Paul', 'England John']
```

```
arr.uniq.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s,h| h[s[/\S+/]] += 1 }
  #=> {"England"=>2, "USA"=>1}
```

This requires two passes through the array (`arr.uniq` being the first). To make only a single pass one could do the following.

```
require 'set'

uniques = Set.new
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s,h| h[s[/\S+/]] += 1 if uniques.add?(s) }
  #=> {"England"=>2, "USA"=>1}
```

See the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument (called the *default value*), and also [Set#add?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F).

It's not clear to me which of the two calculations would generally be faster.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more verbose than the other solutions but does not use  `transform_values`from ActiveSupport.

```
require "set"

data = ["England John", "England Ben", "USA Paul", "England John", "Switzerland Pascal"]

names_per_country = data.each_with_object({}) do |country_and_name, accu|
  country, name = country_and_name.split(" ")
  country_data = accu[country] ||= Set.new
  country_data << name
end

names_per_country.each do |country, names|
  puts "#{country} has #{names.size} unique name(s)"
end

# => England has 2 unique names
# => USA has 1 unique names
# => Switzerland has 1 unique names
```

This solution first transforms the array to a `Hash` structure, where the *key* is the country name and the *value* is a `Set`.
I've chosen `Set` because it does take care of the *unique* part of your question automatically (a `Set` can not contain duplicates).

After that you can find the number of unique names per country by checking the `size` of the `Set`. 
You can also find the names (the elements of the `Set` if required)