# How to declare Hash.new(0) with 0 default value for counting objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby

I'm trying to iterate through an array of digits and count how many times each digit is found in the array.

In ruby it's easy, I just declare a `Hash.new(0)` and that hash is already been set up for counting from 0 as a value. For example:

```rb
arr = [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]
counter = Hash.new(0)
arr.each { |num| counter[num] += 1 } # which gives {1=> 3, 0=> 5}
```

I wanted to do the same thing in JavaScript but `let counter = {}` gives me `{ '0': NaN, '1': NaN }`.

Do you have any idea how to create that same Hash as an Object in JavaScript?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ in _Ruby_ you are abusing `each` for reducing. It should be done as `arr.each_with_object(Hash.new{0}) { |num, counter| counter[num] += 1 }`.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ in _Ruby_ it might be more consise with `[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1].group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:count) #⇒ {1=>3, 0=>5}`.

Comment: You can't do this, JavaScript has no analog for `Hash.new(0)` in Ruby. You need to test whether the key exists before attempting to increment its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ECMAScript does not have default values for missing keys in objects [the same way Ruby does for `Hash`es](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-default-3D). You can, however, use *dynamic introspective metaprogramming* to do something similar, using [ECMAScript `Proxy` objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-proxy-objects):

```
const defaultValue = 42;
const proxyHandler = {
    get: (target, name) => name in target ? target[name] : defaultValue
};
const underlyingObject = {};

const hash = new Proxy(underlyingObject, proxyHandler);

1 in hash
//=> false
1 in underlyingObject
//=> false

hash[1]
//=> 42
underlyingObject[1]
//=> undefined
```

So, you could do something like this:

```
arr.reduce(
    (acc, el) => { acc[el]++; return acc }, 
    new Proxy(
        {},
        { get: (target, name) => name in target ? target[name] : 0 }
    )
)
//=> Proxy [ { '0': 5, '1': 3 }, { get: [Function: get] } ]
```

However, this is still not equivalent to the Ruby version, where [the keys of the `Hash` can be arbitrary objects](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) whereas [the property keys in an ECMAScript object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors) can only be [`String`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string-objects)s and [`Symbol`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-symbol-objects)s.

The direct equivalent of a Ruby `Hash` is an [ECMAScript `Map`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-map-objects).

Unfortunately, ECMAScript `Map`s don't have default values either. We could use the same trick we used for objects and create a `Proxy`, but that would be awkward since we would have to intercept accesses to the [`get`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-map.prototype.get) method of the `Map`, then extract the arguments, call [`has`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-map.prototype.has), and so on.

Luckily, `Map`s are designed to be subclassable:

```
class DefaultMap extends Map {
    #defaultValue;

    constructor(iterable=undefined, defaultValue=undefined) {
        super(iterable);
        this.#defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    get(key) {
        return this.has(key) ? super.get(key) : this.#defaultValue;
    }
}

const hash = new DefaultMap(undefined, 42);

hash.has(1)
//=> false

hash.get(1)
//=> 42
```

This allows us to do something like this:

```
arr.reduce(
    (acc, el) => acc.set(el, acc.get(el) + 1), 
    new DefaultMap(undefined, 0)
)
//=> DefaultMap [Map] { 1 => 3, 0 => 5 }
```

Of course, once we start defining our own `Map` anyway, we might just go the whole way:

```
class Histogram extends DefaultMap {
    constructor(iterator=undefined) {
        super(undefined, 0);

        if (iterator) {
            for (const el of iterator) {
                this.set(el);
            }
        }
    }

    set(key) {
        super.set(key, this.get(key) + 1)
    }
}

new Histogram(arr)
//=> Histogram(2) [Map] { 1 => 3, 0 => 5 }
```

This also demonstrates a very important lesson: the choice of data structure can vastly influence the complexity of the algorithm. With the correct choice of data structure (a `Histogram`), the algorithm *completely vanishes*, all we do is instantiate the data structure.

Note that the same is true in Ruby also. [By choosing the right data structure (there are several implementations of a `MultiSet` floating around the web), your entire algorithm vanishes and all that is left is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5128661/2988):

```ruby
require 'multiset'

Multiset[*arr]
#=> #<Multiset:#5 0, #3 1>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript you do it with [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const reducer = (acc, e) => acc.set(e, (acc.get(e) || 0) + 1);
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1].reduce(reducer, new Map())
//⇒ Map(2) {1 => 3, 0 => 5}
```

Comment: That's the "correct" solution in Ruby as well `arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|el, acc| acc[el] += 1 }`. The question is how to get a dictionary with default values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map`,

- initialize `hash` as `Map`
- Loop through array, if key is already present in `hash` increase it's value by `1` else set it to `1`

```js
let arr = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
let hash = new Map()

arr.forEach(val => {
  hash.set(val, (hash.get(val) || 0) + 1)
})

console.log([...hash])
```

Comment: I've done that idea with an if else statement:    `  let hash = new Map()
  arr.forEach(num => { 
    hash[num] ? hash[num]++ : hash[num] = 1
  } ) ` . Is there any way in JavaScript to avoid the If else statement and just do the fast counting like in my ruby example in the post?

Comment: @Commando using `if else` statement doesn't affect performance much, the one i posted uses a `logical OR`

Comment: Is there any benefit to using `Map`, `set`, and `get` vs the hash literal `{}` with `[]` and `[]=`?

Comment: @maxpleaner: ECMAScript objects only allow strings or symbols as keys. Anything else will be implicitly converted to strings. Depending on how close you want the analogy to Ruby to be, that could be a problem. E.g. in Ruby, I can have `{ 0 => 23, '0' => 42 }`, in ECMAScript, those would be the same key. `Map`s are the ECMAScript equivalent to Ruby `Hash`es.