# do we have map like collections in nodejs as in java?

Tags: node.js, collections

Do we have any colllections like map in nodejs. I would like to have a collection which can store my key value. Is there something like the same in nodejs

Comment: There are objects and Maps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Map`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-map-objects) was added to the ECMAScript standard library in [ECMAScript 2015](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map-objects). This is not just "something like a map", this *is* a map.

Here is a question with an answer of mine that uses a `Map`: [*How to declare Hash.new(0) with 0 default value for counting objects in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57644639/2988)