# Jascript use custom default return type for bracket-notation

Tags: javascript, dictionary, hash

I want to achieve the following behavior:

For a certain JS object, if I use `bracket-notation` to access a key that is not defined, I want it to return `0` instead of `undefined`, similar to how Ruby `Hash.new(0)` behaves.

Is there a way I can go about implementing such behavior or anything in JavaScript that already exists which I could use instead?

currently having trouble sifting through noise related to this topic (mainly do to a lack of knowing google terms on this topic), any google terms I could use or docs I could read to better understand this would also be a huge help.

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57643313/how-to-declare-hash-new0-with-0-default-value-for-counting-objects-in-javascri

Answer (score 0):

You could use the logical OR operator "||".
This will act as a fallback if the property is not defined.

```js
const obj = {hello:'world'};
console.log(obj['hello'] || 0);
console.log(obj['somethingelse'] || 0);
```

I found MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) to be a great resource for JS related questions.

More on the logical OR operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

More on property accessors (bracket notation): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: the `||` test for truthiness, which will run into trouble if the key is defined with a falsy value. for example: `const obj = {hello:'world', foo: false}; console.log(obj['foo'] || 0); // logs 0`

Comment: I am actually passing an object into a charting library (d3-geomap) that is going to use it internally to extract data from it, i want the object to return `0` by default so if i pass `{USA: 1234}` it will set the rest of the countries as having `0` users by default without me having to specify it manually for each country, the data is coming from an API.